# Criteria Add all the tables from the entity class when it only needs part of it

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, criteria, hibernate-criteria

when i create a count query with hibernate - Criteria - add all the possible table from the entity class as left join which is bad performance .

The entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
Public Class Employees {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "lz_job_stat_id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "departments_id")
    private Departments  departments;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "managers_id")
    private Managers  managers;

}
```

And the criteria :

```
public class EmployeeDao {

    public List<EmpDao> findIt(){
        .....
        Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria().setFetchMode("departments", FetchMode.SELECT);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("managers.deleted", false));

        crit.setProjection(Projections.count("id"));
        return crit.list();
    }
}
```

And the produced SQL :

```
select count() as y0_ 
from employees this_ 
left outer join departments department3_ 
    on this_.department_id=department3_.department_id
left outer join managers manager2_ 
    on this_.manager_id=manager2_.manager_id
```

now when i try the crit.list - it create a left join for all the possible tables.

when its not supposed to create a join for all of them.
isnt Criteria smart enought to know i dont need this tables ? only the one i use the `"WHERE CLAUSE"`
is there a way to explicitly tell Criteria **"DO NOT JOIN THIS TABLES !!!"**
without SQL

Comment: Hibernate: 
    /* criteria query */ select
        count(*) as y0_ 
    from
        employees this_ 
    left outer join
        departments department3_ 
            on this_.department_id=department3_.department_id 
     left outer join
   managers manager2_ 
            on this_.manager_id=manager2_.manager_id

Comment: Why don't we see the restriction on manager.deleted = false ? Are you sure it is the query generated by this criteria ?

Comment: Its was missed on the copy paste .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify fetch type on `ManyToOne` annotation:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "departments_id")
private Departments  departments;
```

or IMHO more preferably in criteria:

```
criteria.setFetchMode("departments", FetchMode.SELECT)
```

Comment: in this case, it should be used on departments rather than managers, because there is a restriction on managers, but not on department, which is the unexpected outer join @Francy is getting.

Comment: I have tried the .setFetchMode and i keep getting left outer join for other entities .

Comment: Updated, is there away to "Don't- Fetch"  prevent from joining all the possible table entities ?

Comment: LAZY  deprecated and now works as select :

 @Deprecated
 public static final FetchMode LAZY = SELECT;

Comment: @Francy If you have condition on Managers table you must include it to join clause.